# How to setup a Active Directory environment test?

Tags: testing, active-directory, vmware

The project I´m working on needs to auth its users against AD, and as a fallback check against its own user base. Now I need to test it outside the production environment.

What is the best method to setup a Active Directory test environment? Currently I´m downloading a Windows 2003 Virtual PC [image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=77f24c9d-b4b8-4f73-99e3-c66f80e415b6&DisplayLang=en), and planning a VMWare virtual LAN.

Is there any problem in that approach?

Comment: To help other noobs like me: you will need something like Virtual PC (http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) to be able to run the Win 2003 trial virtual machine (VHD file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this environment suppose to simulate as many ActiveDirectory installations as possible, or is it to just test that authentication works against a DC?

At a minimum, you will want to setup two Domain Controllers, a Primary and a Secondary. You will want to also setup accounts with a variety of account states (password expired, account expired,  account lockout, etc).

Some other issues to think about:

Is your domain running as a Win2000 functional Domain? or a Windows 2003 functional Domain?
If you have multiple domains, will you support Universal Group membership? 
If you have multiple forrests, will you support Cross-Forest Trust relationships?

Comment: That´s a lot of questions I´m unable to answer, I´m afraid. Perhaps just backing up the production setup and deploying on test env works?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about all those questions, but depending on what you are trying to model (your AD environment vs potential customer's AD environment) you may need to have more thought put into your setup.

Answer (score 2):

You should think about multi-domain and multi-forest environments, as well as just having multiple domain controllers in the domain you're authenticating against. You're going to need more than a single VM to do that.

Comment: With the server sitting on vmware and my app running on the host SO, will I need another vm?